# Open up a react component just below the clicked component

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I Have a list in react which can take up any number of rows 
I have to render a component just below the clicked list component 
The wireframe attached shows the list 
https://wireframe.cc/oAe7eQ
[image]
The second wireframe attached shows after the component is rendered 
[image]
What should be the structure to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Here are the list of steps that could help you achieve it.

1. So you can create a Modal for each list element.
2. This independent Modal component gets called with onClick event handler attached to the List element.
3. On the click you pass the row data as props to this new sub component Modal.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @YashSharma yes Modal is a pop way of doing it but even if you don't want a pop thing, you can keep a boolean flag as true or false and you can toggle it based on the click on the item lists and render the detailed view part of the list using renderIf ...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question
The list can be of any number of rows 
So if the item from the second row is selected then the component shoul be rendered after the second row
So the question being how to decide the position of the component

Comment: ya so your component will be placed within a boolean render if condition after you have iterated over all your rows ... so no matter what size rows you have ...once you do array.maps(row), something like this to loop through, after that you can render anything